# A program that asks user for file name and opens it - what did I do wrong?

Tags: c++

[image]

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream> 
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        //This declares the input and output files.
        ifstream input;
        ofstream output;
        string filename;

        int value, total = 0;

        cout << "Enter the file name: " << endl;
        cin >> filename;

        //This function opens file.
        input.open(filename.c_str());

       //This checks to see if the file can be opened, 
       //if yes, then it will calculate sum.
       if(input)
       {
          while(!input.eof()) 
             {
                input >> value;      
                total += value;
             }
       }

       //This closes the input file.
       input.close();

      //This opens the output file.
       output.open("sum.txt");

     //This is where a file will open and the calculated sum will be shown.
     if(output.is_open())
     output << total;

     //This is if the file can not be opened.
     else
        cout << "Could not access the file." << endl;

    //This closes the output file.
    output.close();

   return 0;
   }
```

The comment I received back about my code:

"There's a minor bug in fileAdder where the last value to be read is being added twice. It appears that this is an issue with text files in Linux/Unix ending with a newline."

To fix it, I tried changing:

```
int value, total = 0;
```

into:

```
int value; // value is some positive number n
int total = 0; // total holds the sum of the first n positive numbers
int number; // the amount of numbers
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. We're not supposed to answer questions about broken Code, please see http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Could you reword your question?

Comment: Based on the title you have successfully opened a file. The comment you got back specifically tells you what is wrong. You need to check the end of file before you add the value to the total.

Comment: I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way! Please see our [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information.

Comment: I disagree that this code is broken, it just doesn't do what was expected of it for quite an obscure reason for a noob.   Also the comment/explanation that was given is misleading at best.  Also there is plenty of things that could be improved with the code itself (I mean that in a nice way)

Answer (score 2):

From just glancing at the code I noticed these things that might help you in future.  Overall the code is really clean and easy to read, its got meaningful variable names and is well commented.  I'm guessing you are relatively new to programming, and I know I have said these things to many people on here before and I have been guilty of everyone (some a bit more recently than I like to admit :) ) so these are meant as constructive comments, but since I'm a programmer tact is not my strong suite.

1. `using namespace std;` The purpose of namespaces is to separate classes and functions names from each other and stopping ambiguity.  The using statement gets rid of the namespace and reintroduces ambiguity.  Basically don't use using.
2. One statement per line.  Putting two statements on a line makes the code easier to write but harder to read and its read many more times than its written.
3. Inconsistent indenting and use of braces.
4. If you fail to open the output file you are still closing it, this is not a good idea.
5. As to what you did wrong, IMO when you read the input value you should check that its a number, before you add it.  Its nothing to do with Linux/Unix a Windows box could do the same.  Have a think what would happen if you had a file that contained:  1 2 3 Word 5